# How to open a new tab in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I've looked but i cannot seem to find an 'Open New Tab' option for the robot framework. I've seen things that are close but not quite what i want. The goal is to be in one tab, do something that would send an email, and then open a 2nd tab to check the email. I'm using BrowserStack so a second window is not an option.

I attempted to use the image horizon library to send a Command+T but it ends up performing that command in whatever window has focus at the moment. When running from the terminal, it'll open a new terminal tab instead of sending the combination to the browserstack window.

Comment: Please share code.

Comment: Here's the code as it currently is. The "staging" is the title of the tab. 

`press combination    key.command    key.t
Select window    staging`